# Subdirectory to subdirectory UrlRewrite with filename

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to rewrite all requests from e.g **/img/logo.svg** to go to **/dist/img/logo.svg**

Any idea? I'm sure it's something obvious.

```
    <rule name="RewriteImgFolder" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^/img/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/img/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your url is `http://localhost/img/logo.svg`, your url rewrite rule will not work.

You could remove the "/" in the match url.

More details, you could refer to below rules:

```
<rule name="RewriteImgFolder" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^img/(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/img/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```